# Signtool validation fails when signing and validating are done in different machines

Tags: security, certificate, exe, sign, signtool

I am signing an exe from a machine using a cer file. Then when I validate the EXE using the signtool.exe from the same machine, it succeeds. But when I try to validate it using the same .cer installed in another machine it fails with the following error.

```
SignTool Error: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root
    certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.

 Number of errors: 1
```

In this other machine in which I'm trying to validate, the .cer file has been installed into the Trusted Root certificates set. But still why I am getting this error? any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The certificate you use for signing has been issued by which certificate?

Comment: I didn't use a CA cert. I just created a simple certificate using the cert.exe

Comment: Well then the certificate is unknown and untrusted on other computers. You need to install the certificate (without the private key) on each and every computer you want to use (and verify) the executable.

Comment: Yes I've installed the certificate to the Trusted Root branch.